# Using C file without header in a .mm file objective-c / xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a .c file (no header) that has some functions in it.  I have another .mm file that should be calling functions in that .c file.  This works in the xcode project I am taking the file from.  However, when I add this file to my own project and do this.  I am getting the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "Init(Context*)", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView initWithFrame:] in EAGLView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I do have this line in my .mm file:

```
int Init(Context *context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a reason the `.c` file doesn't have a header - the functions inside are meant to be private, and there's a chance they're defined as `static`. If that's the case, remove the `static` keyword and recompile.

Comment: The function is in the .c file like this, non-static.

int Init(Context *context)
{
...
}

Comment: @user2158259 In this case, something else's wrong. How'bout providing more information?

Comment: I decided to just part that particular .c file to objective-c and that fixed the problem I was having.  Thanks for the help though.